# Prove that the reciprocal of a polynomial function $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $R$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the reciprocal of a polynomial function $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $R$.

(It is provided that the reciprocal of the function exists. In other words, $f(x)$ is never zero for any value of $x$.)

I go by the way:

Let $g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$, where $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + . . . + a_nx^n.$

Now we have to show that $g(x)$ is uniformly contnuous on $R.$

Then

$|g(x)-g(x_o)| = |\frac{1}{f(x)} - \frac{1}{f(x_0)}|$
$=|x - x_0||\frac{a_1(x - x_0) + a_2(x^2 - x_0^2) + . . . + a_n(x^n - x_0^n)}{f(x)f(x_0)}|$

Then how to proceed??

Comment: By "the reciprocal exists" you mean that $f(x)$ has no real zeros?

Comment: It means that, $f(x)$ is not zero for any $x \in R.$

Comment: Either $f$ is constant - then $1/f$ is also constant, and constant functions are uniformly continuous. Or $f$ is not constant. Then $\lim\limits_{\lvert x\rvert \to \infty} \lvert f(x)\rvert =\,?$

Comment: It would be either $+ \inf$ or $- inf.$ But how does it help?

Comment: I took the absolute value, so $+\infty$. It shows that $\lim\limits_{\lvert x\rvert\to\infty} \frac{1}{f(x)} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a partial proof by contradiction. If $g$ wasn't uniformly continuous, then there would exist a number $\epsilon_0>0$ and two sequences $\{x_n\}_n$ and $\{y_n\}_n$ of real numbers such that $\lim_n |x_n-y_n| =0$ but $|g(x_n)-g(y_n)| > \epsilon_0$.

If both sequences diverge to infinity, then $|g(x_n)-g(y_n)|$ tends to zero: indeed $g=1/f$ and $f$ diveges to infinity at infinity. Contradiction!

If both sequences remain bounded, then they would converge to, say, $x_0$ and $y_0$ after extracting subsequences. Again, since $g$ is continuous, $|g(x_n)-g(y_n)|$ tends to $|g(x_0)-g(y_0)|=0$ because $x_0=y_0$ (why?). Contradiction!